# How to reduce size of apk file?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which is containing .apk file of 13.56MB. It is containing 70 .png images. And there is image transparency so it have to be in .png format.
And i have to add more images. so do you have any solution to reduce the memory of an application.

Comment: remove unused images from resources & convert .png to .jpeg format... It will reduce your apk size.

Comment: If it's resources that you cannot compress/9-patch & you're going to be adding a ton more of them you could look in to [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html).

Comment: Good Question +1 for it.

Answer (score 2):

Please used 9-patch images.

Nine patch images are especially useful when designing buttons. Custom drawn buttons can look distorted and pixelated when their borders are stretched in addition to the rest of the image.

[Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and [other resource](http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following things

1. use tiny png to reduce size of images without loosing quality https://tinypng.com
2. Use tool AndroidUnusedResources to remove unneccessary resources
   https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/
3. Repackge jars or libraries using JarJar.jar tool. If you are using GooglePlayServices.jar then its too large

Answer (score 0):

Batter way to reduce size of apk. Split apk and `minifyEnabled=true`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```